# Problem in accessing registration page using URL

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

I have developed a registration page where I am trying to access the page by giving the URL on my google chrome. the URL is: localhost:8080/Registration. But every time it takes me to the apache tomcat login page. How can I fix this error?

```
package net.javaguides.springboot.web;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import net.javaguides.springboot.service.UserService;
import net.javaguides.springboot.web.dto.UserRegistrationDTO;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/Registration")
public class UserRegistrationController {

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@GetMapping
public String showRegistrationForm() {
    return "Registration.html";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it redirecting to **localhost:8080/login**?

If yes, it is because of spring-boot-starter-security, it adds default security to your application.

You can disable it either of following two methods.

- Remove following dependency from your pom.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

OR

- By adding following configuration class, this option will give you more flexibility.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll();
    }
}
```

This snippet will bypass authentication for all endpoints.